# Apache2 - can't access any page other than the default index.html

Tags: server, apache2, php, phpmyadmin

I followed this guide step-by-step: http://bit.ly/2bWh7xE
When I got to the last step (installing `phpmyadmin`), I was no longer able to access the `info.php` file created earlier.

When I go to localhost, I get the normal apache default page. When I go to `localhost/info.php`, Firefox says `Unable to connect`. The same happens when I go to `localhost/phpmyadmin`.

I apt-get purged everything installed in the tutorial and did it again and the same thing happened after installing phpmyadmin.

The files `/var/www/html/index.html` and `/var/www/html/info.php` have the same permissions and both belong to `www-data`.

Comment: Do you have a domain? if you do does only index.html work? Create another html file in /var/www/html. After that type domain.com/nameofhtmlfile.html or localhost/name.html and see if that works.